Read OGC WMS tile data with Mapnik
I am using Mapnik 3.1 with python-mapnik 3.0 and would like to have a WMS layer in my program. Users should be able to add a WMS server and see the image data of the WMS layer from that server as Mapnik layer. From the documentation it looks like the GDAL driver might work, since GDAL supports WMS. I tried this, but only get a white/empty map back from the WMS server. This is what I am doing (using a public WMS):
style = mapnik.Style()
rule = mapnik.Rule()
rule.symbols.append(mapnik.RasterSymbolizer())
style.rules.append(rule)
map.append_style('Raster Style',style)

url = 'https://ows.mundialis.de/services/service?REQUEST=GetMap&service=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&layers=OSM-WMS&styles=&format=image/png&bgcolor=0xFFFFFF&transparent=false&CRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=51.983164,9.249335,52.004952,9.271598&width=1000&height=1000' # Public WMS
lyr = mapnik.Layer(f'GDAL WMS Layer with URL {url}')
lyr.datasource = mapnik.Gdal(file=f'WMS:{url}')
lyr.styles.append('Raster Style')

Using gdalinfo on the URL shows correct WMS info (as it seems to me). The map is also configured to show an area with data (at least OSM data is rendered if I remove the WMS layer again).
Am I missing something or is there another way to do this?

WMS doesn't serve tiles, it serves whole maps that are created from layers so you will need to add a layer name to your request some how

Thank you, that's a good point, I corrected my wording. I tested more and managed to create a proper WMS URL that returns a map image. It still doesn't work with Mapnik though.
